# Mockito @Before annotation: variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, junit, annotations, mockito

Ist there a way to use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` by using @Mock annotation?

I have

```
PageContext context = mock(PageContext.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

and I would like something like:

```
@Mock
PageContext context;
```

assume there are all the `@Before` initIalizing methods needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work fine. Please check and let me know:

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
PageContext context;
```